# Generate random in secure message transfer

Tags: public-key, symmetric, pseudo-random-generator, integrity, non-repudiation

I’m doing a school assignment about secure communications between a Server and a Client.
Basically, messages are exchanged between the clients and the server and these communications must implement confidentiality, authentication, integrity and non-repudiation.

Imagine I have to send a message from the client to the server. This is what I’ve idealized:

- Client and Server both generate their public/private keys;
- Their public keys are shared between them;
- Client, generates a session key using 'AES';
- Client encrypts the message using the session key and sends this to the server;
- Client encrypts the session key with the Server public key and send this to the server;
- Client creates a hash of the message and encrypts this hash with the client's private key and sends this to the server;
- Server uses is private key to get the session key;
- Server uses session key to decrypt the message;
- Server decrypts the hash with the client's public key;
- Server creates hash of message and compares with the above hash.

I’m thinking of creating a new session key every time the Client sends a message to the Server.

1. Is this the way it should be done?
2. In the generation of the keys I have to use a random number. How do i do this?

My thoughts for #2 are:

```
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128,new SecureRandom());
```

Or this:

```
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128,  System.nanoTime());
```

Or should I use other way? I'm asking this because I don't know the best way to generate the seed.

Comment: don't use `nanoTime`

Comment: You are basically making a hybrid cryptosystem. I don't understand something though: The client sends an encrypted message, and *then* sends the key. Why not share the key before any message is sent? Second, a hash itself is not a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). This is especially important in your scheme as you don't use an [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (which means an adversary can repeat a message and the server would accept it). Finally, take a look at [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5458/5231). I hope this helps.

Comment: @rath Hi. Thanks for your comments. Key is not shared before, because a new key is generated in every msg. I believe this makes more difficult to "crack" the key. Isn't it? Should I use other method??.. Relatively to the hash, when the Client creates a hash of the message and then encrypts this hash with the client's private key and sends this to the server, isn't this guaranteeing the integrity of the message? Sorry but I was lost in the IV and how I should generate or not the random :(

Comment: If you generate a proper AES key (with PBKDF2 or Scrypt) it certainly does make brute-force harder, but brute-forcing AES an unfeasible strategy because it's *completely impractical to do so* (you can google how much time it takes with a proper key). That's why it's the standard after all. By renewing the key for each message you defeat the purpose of a hybrid cryptosystem, which is to avoid expensive operations associated with assymetric ciphers and use the faster symmetric ones. You do need to use an IV though. [Some ideas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) on that

Comment: @rath Thanks. But after a while the AES key should be renewed. Wright? Maybe every hour?

Comment: Like @CodesInChaos [already commented](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12306/generate-random-in-secure-message-transfer#comment26205_12306): don't use `nanoTime`. Instead, go for `SecureRandom` as that actually returns a crypto-secure random number… which is what you want/need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the well established TLS (Transport Layer Security) protocol to achieve the first three properties and modify it to include a digital signature for non-repudiation*. However, strictly speaking, non-repudiation requires the use of certificates from a CA so that the signature can be verified by any third party.