# Is there a method to combine encryption and ring signing?

Tags: signature, protocol-design

There's the well-known question on whether to [sign or encrypt first](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5458/2663). However, if instead a message is to be ring-signed such that either recipient could be the actual signer, is there any scheme that combines signing and encrypting in one "atomic" step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like there are conventional [signcryption schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signcryption) combining digital signatures with encryption into a single primitive, there are also **ring signcryption schemes** that realize the same for ring signatures and encryption. Look for instance [here](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=10192&context=infopapers&sei-redir=1&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.at%2Fscholar%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dring%2Bsigncryption%26btnG%3D%26as_sdt%3D1%252C5%26as_sdtp%3D#search=%22ring%20signcryption%22) or just ask [Google scholar](http://scholar.google.at/scholar?hl=en&q=ring+signcryption&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=).