# IND-CCA game proof of Encrypt-then-Mac

Tags: provable-security, chosen-ciphertext-attack

In [[BN07, Subsection 4.3]](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/oem.pdf), the authors show that if a symmetric scheme $\mathcal{SE}$ is IND-CPA and a MAC $\mathcal{MA}$ is EUF-CMA (though they use the SUF-CMA notation, but I think it refers to the same notion?), then the symmetric scheme $\mathcal{SE'}$, constructed via the Encrypt-the-MAC technique, is IND-CCA secure.

Unfortunately, they show it the following way:

1. $\mathcal{SE}$ being IND-CPA implies $\mathcal{SE'}$ being IND-CPA
2. $\mathcal{MA}$ being EUF-CMA implies $\mathcal{SE'}$ being INT-CTXT
3. $\mathcal{SE'}$ being INT-CPA and INT-CTXT implies it being IND-CCA

I struggle to see how a game-based proof of this would look-like. For instance, let us say we have an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that breaks IND-CCA security of $\mathcal{SE'}$, and let us consider a reduction $\mathcal{R}$ that has access to this adversary and tries to break either IND-CPA security of $\mathcal{SE}$ or the EUF-CMA security of $\mathcal{MA}$. How would the reduction proceed, since it does not have access to a decryption oracle?

Assuming we work in the real-or-random setup, I understand the reduction can record the queries that $\mathcal{A}$ does in order to know how it should answer on these particular queries. However, how is it possible for $\mathcal{R}$ to answer decryption queries which are not stored in its database? If we consider that $\mathcal{A}$ won't try to query the decryption of some $y$ without previously having asked the encryption of $x$ which resulted in $y=\mathrm{Enc}(x)$, then what's the point of giving a decryption oracle to $\mathcal{A}$ at all? Should $\mathcal{R}$ answer with a random $r=\mathrm{Enc}^{-1}(y)$, hoping that $\mathcal{A}$ won't ever query $x$ such that $r\neq y=f(x)$? In that case doesn't this potentially break $\mathcal{A}$'s strategy to break IND-CCA?

Comment: The SUF-CMA they use is _strong_ unforgeability, i.e. an adversary can't even come up with a new tag for a message they already received a tag from the oracle for. What they call "WUF-CMA" tends to be more in-line with standard definitions of EUF-CMA (the definitions are in the paper as Figure 6)

Comment: Yes, I tried to read [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44210/86913) but unfortunately, neither this answer (at the best of my understanding) nor BN07 gives a definition of EUF-CMA. The thing is, I'm working on [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/237.pdf) which states that EUF-CMA+IND-CPA => IND-CCA, citing BN07 as the original, classical proof for this fact. A problem arises however: BN07 states that IND-CPA+WUF-CMA is not necessarily IND-CCA (contrarily to IND-CPA+SUF-CMA). Hence, we would have something like SUF-CMA => EUF-CMA => WUF-CMA?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken and BN07 shows SUF-CMA + IND-CPA => IND-CCA**3**, since we're using an authentication mechanism (as stated in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81442/86913))? But I'm almost sure CEV20 tries to define qIND-qCCA**2**...

Comment: A direct proof of IND-CPA + EUF-CMA => IND-CCA2 can be found in [Boneh-Shoup's cryptobook](https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf) (Theorem 9.2), EUF-CMA is defined by the attack game 6.1.

Comment: Looking at CEV20, it seems that their definition of EUF-CMA (taken from BZ13) tends to be more in-line with classical SUF-CMA (though it's tricky to define these security notions properly in the quantum setting, see recent results on defining security for MAC, e.g. [AMRS20](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1150.pdf)).